# Forgetting a text widget in python

Tags: tkinter, python-3.2

```
root = Tk()
S = Scrollbar(root)
T = Text(root, height=4, width=50)
S.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
T.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
S.config(command=T.yview)
T.config(yscrollcommand=S.set)
quote = """HAMLET: To be, or not to be--that is the question:
Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer
The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune
Or to take arms against a sea of troubles
And by opposing end them. To die, to sleep--
No more--and by a sleep to say we end
The heartache, and the thousand natural shocks
That flesh is heir to. 'Tis a consummation
Devoutly to be wished."""
T.insert(END, quote)
mainloop(  )

def donothing():
   filewin = Toplevel(root)
   button = Button(filewin, text="Do nothing button")
   button.pack()
   filemenu.entryconfig("History of Mac and Pc", state="disabled")

root = Tk()

root.title("Mac vs Pc Quiz")
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Shakespeare",command=history_pc)
filemenu.add_command(label="Hamlet", command=donothing)



filemenu.add_separator()

filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="English", menu=filemenu)



root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Is there a way i can close the text after i scroll down or whatever as long as it closes. What i mean by is that when u start the program i want that to show up after closing the paragraph Any help would be helpful, thanks in advance

Comment: Anyone know how i can do that? i tried doing T.pack_forget() but it deletes the passage

Comment: pack_forget, forgets everything about that widget so when you pack it again, you need to assign every option just like you did in the first place. Try to use grid geometry manager if you are planning to use that widget again with same options. [grid_remove()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_remove-method) would be helpful to you. Also, difference between [grid_forget() and grid_remove()](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html)

Comment: Is there a reason  you want to hide it, rather than just re-inserting the original text into the widget? Is there a specific reason you're destroying and recreating the root window? That's a highly unusual thing to do, especially when you are a beginner at tkinter.

Comment: cuz when i open the menu hamlet the Shakespeare option still shows up displaying the text

Comment: any idea @BryanOakley what i can do i got the solution but i don't think its efficient

Comment: Your first step should be to read some documentation. Start here: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html or here http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm or here http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text.html